# Selecting multiple file extensions, when some don't exist

Tags: bash

I want to select all files with extension f, F and F90. Currently I am trying something like

```
echo *.f *.F *.f90
```

However, if there are no .f files in the directory (and there is always one of the three) I get left with the *.f, i.e it echos

```
*.f file1.F file2.f90
```

Which, if I want to delete them will always complain as *.f doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shopt -s nullglob` will fix this in Bash, but is not portable.

Comment: I googled nullglob and found this page - http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob - before I tried it. When I tried "set -o nullglob" it complained of an invalid option name. When I tried "shopt -s nullglob" from the article it worked! Any reason yours didn't work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, quoted it out of memory. Will correct the answer.